# Passing mapping value to mappings in ApplyMapping.apply in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am trying to execute a Glue job by passing the mapping value at run time using
[Run with parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I64mr.png)

The value of the input mapping parameter that I am passing is:

```
[
("rec_id", "string","rec_id", "string" ),
("id_", "string", "updated_id", "string"),
("parent_act_inst_id_", "string", "parent_act_inst_id_", "string"),
("proc_def_key_", "string", "proc_def_key_", "string"),
("proc_def_id_", "string", "proc_def_id_", "string"),
("duration_", "decimal", "duration_", "decimal"),
("act_inst_state_", "decimal", "act_inst_state_", "decimal"),
("sequence_counter_", "decimal", "sequence_counter_", "decimal"),
("tenant_id_", "string", "tenant_id_", "string"),
("removal_time_", "string", "removal_time_", "string"),
("dw_lod_tmp", "timestamp", "dw_lod_tmp", "timestamp"),
]
```

And I am trying to read the input mapping value (parameter name is ip_mapping) as:

```
applyMap = args['ip_mapping']
```

And use it in the ApplyMapping.apply:

```
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=S3bucket_node1,
    mappings=applyMap,
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)
```

However I get an error as

```
TypeError: Mapping must be specified as a tuple. Got [
```

I think It is reading the whole input mapping value as a string.
Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue or has any suggestions to how to fix it.

I tried converting the string to a tuple.